# just can't get perl working as expected ( conditionals and variable declaring )

Tags: perl, cgi

**EDIT:**

I will try a better explication this time, this is the exact code from my script.

```
#use warnings;
#use Data::Dumper;
open(my $tmp_file, ">>", "/tmp/some_bad.log") or die "Can not open log file: $!\n";
#if( $id_client != "")
@allowed_locations = ();
#print $tmp_file "Before the if: ". Data::Dumper->Dump([\@allowed_locations, $id_client]) . "";
if( $id_client )
{
#    print $tmp_file "Start the if: ". Data::Dumper->Dump([\@allowed_locations, $id_client]) . "";
#    my $q = "select distinct id_location from locations inner join address using (id_db5_address) inner join zona_rural_detaliat using (id_city) where id_client=$id_client";
#    my $st =  &sql_special_transaction($sql_local_host, $sql_local_database, $sql_local_root, $sql_local_root_password, $q);
#    print $tmp_file "Before the while loop: ref(st)='". ref($st) . "\n";
#    while((my $id)=$st->fetchrow())
#    {
#       print $tmp_file "Row the while loop: ". Data::Dumper->Dump([$id])  . "";
#       my $id = 12121212;
#       push(@allowed_locations, $id);
#    }
#    print $tmp_file "After the while loop: ref(st)='". ref($st) . "\n";
#    my($a) = 1;
#} else {
#    my($a) = 0;    
}
#print $tmp_file "After the if: ". Data::Dumper->Dump([\@allowed_locations, $id_client]) . "";
close($tmp_file) or die "Can not close file: $!\n";
#&html_error(@allowed_locations);
```

First off all, somebody said that I should try to run it in command line, **the script works fine in command line (no warnings**, It was uncommented then), **but when triyng to load in via apache in the browser it fails**, please see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WKxuuRrvac) where I captured the script behavior, what I tried to show in the video:

I have opened 2 tabs the first doesn't define the variable $id_client, the second defines the variable $id_client that is read from GET: ?id_client=36124 => **$id_client = 36124;** , both of them include the library in the video "**locallib.pl**"

1. When running the script with all the
   new code commented the page loads
2. when uncoment the line that defines
   the **@allowed_locations = ();** the
   script fails
3. leave this definition and uncoment
   the if block, and the definition of
   **my $a;** in the if block; Now the script works fine when $id_client is
   defined, but fails when $id_client
   is not defined
4. Uncoment the else block and the
   definition of **my $a;** in the else
   block. Now the script works fine
   with or without $id_client
5. now comment all the **my $a;**
   definisions and comment the else
   block, the script fails
6. but if I'm using **open()** to open
   a file before the IF, and
   **close()** to close it after the if it does't fail even if the IF block
   is empty and event if there is no
   else block

I have replicated all the steps when running the script in the command line, and the script worked after each step.
I know it sounds like something that cannot be the behavior of the script, but please watch the video (2 minutes), maybe you will notice something that I'm doing wrong there.

Using perl version:

```
[root@db]# perl -v
This is perl, v5.8.6 built for i386-linux-thread-mult
```

Somebody asked if I don't have a test server, answer: NO, my company has a production server that has multiple purposes, not only the web interface, and I cannot risk to update the kernel or the perl version, and cannot risk instaling any debuger, as the company owners say: "If it works, leave it alone", and for them the solution with **my ($a);** is perfect beacause it works, I'm asking here just for me, to learn more about perl, and to understand what is going wrong and what can I do better next time.

**EDIT:**
I had success starting the error logging, and found this in the error log after each step that resulted in a failure I got this messages:
[Thu Jul 15 14:29:19 2010] [error] locallib.pl did not return a true value at /var/www/html/rdsdb4/cgi-bin/clients/quicksearch.cgi line 2.
[Thu Jul 15 14:29:19 2010] [error] Premature end of script headers: quicksearch.cgi

What I found is that this code is at the end of the main code in the locallib.pl after this there are sub definitions, and locallib.pl is a library not a program file, so **it's last statement must returns true.** , a simple **1;** statement at the end of the library ensures that (I put it after sub definitions to ensure that noobody writes code in the main after the 1;) and the problem was fixed.
Don't know why in CLI it had no problem ...

Comment: "and I don't have an else block the script breaks" - could you please provide the exact error/problem that happens when the script breaks?

Comment: Why -1 who ever you are, without any explanation ? Tell my what I said wrong to correct my self next time.

Comment: @Radu everything about your question is wrong; your change can't possibly have the effect you say it has.

Comment: @hobbs That's why I'm asking here, beacause I realy don't understand why this happens, I thing it has something to do with all other thousand of lines of code writen before I even got hired in this company (all is in a library,and hundred of scripts rely on that).I know that I can't modify the library beacause it is huge, bad writen, and all the company rely on it.I start to build a new one using PHP/AJAX, but until is finished I have to add new features to the old one, writen in PERL. I'm a perl beginer but my boss that knows perl doesn't understand the error. Just nedden some expert's help.

Comment: Unless those thousands of lines of code are doing something wrong with the preprocessor, then adding a do-nothing else cannot change the behavior of code, and adding do-nothing variable declarations cannot change the behavior of code **AND** you still haven't described what "the script breaks" means, and I strongly suspect that the code you're showing us isn't the same as the code you're running. And PERL is a Canadian nature conservation group; the programming language is called Perl.

Comment: @hobbs: if you can see my deleted answer then check the comments. Radu is trying to debug this script running it as a CGI program, and he is looking at the 500 Internal Server Error in a web browser and trying to debug using that. Maybe I should have left my question undeleted as a warning to others who try to help him.

Comment: @hobbs - while this does seem like a heisenbug, the OP has fairly clearly described why he is having the issues he is having in debugging, as Kinopiko said. So let's all be a bit more civil and helpful here?

Comment: @Radu - -1 was because originally your question was stating very vaguely and generically what the breakage point was - which made troubleshooting fairly impossible. I didn't downvote you but I was close to doing so. After your clarifications in the comments, I don't believe it is warranted to downvote anymore, and if you update your question with those details in your comments as addendum you might get those downvotes back.

Comment: @hobbs - BTW, I HAVE had Perl heisenbugs before, including having a comment-addition-fixable ones. While this one does sound weird, and you might be correct in your assessment, it doesn't sound downright impossible.

Comment: @Radu - oh, and it might help avoiding downvotes if your subject is not "Perl is bad" as opposed to "I have a heisenbug in Perl I don't understand"

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to your code and fix all those warnings first.  Next, get your program working from the command-line first before attempting to run it as a CGI. Thirdly, don't insult the language you're using, if you are hoping people will help you.

Comment: Did you have a look at apache error log ?

Comment: @Radu: -1 because the question title is not a summary of your problem.

Comment: @Radu = +1 from me for the updates

Comment: @dolmen => a better title ... hm ... how about "perl script fails when in a library I'm using empty conditional, or define a new array" ... If you have any good title I will change it.

Comment: @Radu: the "just can’t get perl working as expected" part of the current title is useless as the question is already tagged with "Perl". You should also read the PerlMonks FAQ: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=174051

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to explicitly check for definedness.

   If you want to enter the loop when $client is defined, 
   use `if ( defined $client )`.

   If you want to enter the loop when $client is defined and a valid integer, 
   use `if ( defined $client && $client =~ /^-?\d+$/ )`.
   I assume it's an integer from the context, if it can be a float, the regex needs to be enhanced - there's a standard Perl library containing pre-canned regexes, including ones to match floats. If you require a non-negative int, drop `-?` from regex's start.

   If you want to enter the loop when $client is defined and a non-zero (and assuming it shouldn't ever be an empty string), 
   use `if ( $client )`.

   If you want to enter the loop when $client is defined and a valid non-zero int,
   use `if ( $client && $client =~ /^-?\d+$/ )`.
2. Your @ids is "undef" when `if` condition is false, which may break the code later on if it relies on @ids being an array. Since you didn't actually specify **how** the script breaks without an `else`, this is the most likely cause.

Please see if this version works (use whichever "if" condition from above you need, I picked the last one as it appears to match the closest witrh the original code's intent - only enter for non-zero integers):

**UPDATED CODE WITH DEBUGGING**

```
use Data::Dumper;
open(my $tmp_file, ">", "/tmp/some_bad.log") or die "Can not open log file: $!\n";
@ids = (); # Do this first so @ids is always an array, even for non-client!
print $tmp_file "Before the if: ". Data::Dumper->Dump([\@ids, $client]) . "\n";
if ( $client && $client =~ /^-?\d+$/ ) # First expression catches undef and zero
{
    print $tmp_file "Start the if: ". Data::Dumper->Dump([\@ids, $client]) . "\n";
    my $st = &sql_query("select id from table where client=$client");
    print $tmp_file "Before the while loop: ref(st)='". ref($st) . "'\n";
    while(my $row = $st->fetchrow())
    {
       print $tmp_file "Row the while loop: ". Data::Dumper->Dump([row])  . "'\n";
       push(@ids, $row->[0]);
    }
    print $tmp_file "After the while loop: ref(st)='". ref($st) . "'\n";
    # No need to undef since both variables are lexically in this block only
}
print $tmp_file "After the if\n";
close($tmp_file) or die "Can not close file: $!\n";
```

Comment: strange as it seems, this does not work. Without the else when $client is not defined it breaks (Internal Server Error),and if client is defined it breaks, i put again in the if a variable declaration my $someVariableName=1; and now when client is defined it works. I realy don't understand why, but this is the only way it works. How to find out the exact error/problem, i have "use warnings;" but nothing is printed to the screen,and nothing in the http logs. Can i personalize the error handling to use my own sub to print to a specific file(I usualy write in PHP,and errors are send to http log)?

Comment: @Radu - it sort of depends on what web server you are running, but either CGI or mod_perl under Apache write standard error into Apache's error log

Comment: @Radu - one way to troubleshoot this is to try to print debugging checkpoints to an explicitly opened temp file from the library: use `File::Temp` or just open a file "/tmp/whatever.mine", and sprincle `print $tmp_filehandle "Checkpoing #N"` statements before the if, after the if, inside, etc..., and add contents of `Data::Dumper->Dump([])` to the print statements as appropriate to see contents of the variables

Answer (score 3):

when checking against a string, == and !=  should be respectively 'eq' or 'ne'

```
if( $client != "" )
```

should be

```
if( $client ne "" )
```

Otherwise you don't get what you're expecting to get.

Comment: $client when defined is numeric.

Comment: But you're testing it against an empty string. DVK probably has your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if( $client != "" )
```

try

```
if ($client)
```

Also, Perl debugging is easier if you

```
 use warnings;
 use strict;
```

Comment: if($client) and if($client != "") is the same and does't solve the 3 issues ( just tried again with both of them ).

Comment: @Radu: `if ($client)` and `if ($client != "")` aren't the same. The first one will not proceed if `$client` is undefined or equal to zero.

Comment: Also, if you're comparing a string use `ne` or `eq`

Comment: Additionally, if you want to check its length use `length()`

Comment: $client if defined is numeric, and if i'm using if($client) without the else I get the same result (the script fails when $client is not defined), tried $client = "" unless defined $client; I get the same result.

Comment: @Radu, did you try `use warnings;` and `use strict;`?

Comment: for strict read the comment I left to @darrenmambo, for warnings ...how to use them, I put "use warnings;" in the script, but where they are printed ? I just get an "Internal Server Error" and nothing is printed in the httpd logs. Hope that it doesn't need a reconfiguration and restart to apache ( I cannot stop the intranet not even for 5 seconds ) :)

Comment: @Radu - don't you have, like, a UAT or DEV or TEST web server??? I probably don't want to know the answer :)

Comment: @DVK or a command line or something. stackoverflow.com is turning into a bad joke.

Comment: @Radu => just because your library is not running under `use strict;` doesn't mean that your code can't be...

Comment: @Eric Strom => You gat that wright
@DVK => Just one server, edited the original question, more details there.
@Kinopiko => I am sorry if I'm being ridiculous, hope you will understand more from the video, in the command line, the script works just fine, in the web browser it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

**Always** begin your script with :

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

these will give you usefull informations.

Then you could write :

```
my @ids;

if (defined $client) {
    @ids = (); # not necessary if you run this part only once
    my $st = sql_query("select id from table where client=$client");
    while( my ($id) = $st->fetchrow ) {
       push @ids, $id;
    }
} else {
    warn '$client not defined';
}

if (@ids) {  # Your query returned something
    # do stuff with @ids
} else {
    warn "client '$client' does not exist in database";
}
```

Comment: To the OP (not M42): And quit debugging in the browser, and quit exposing yourself to bobby tables attacks (http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @runrig => previosly in the library where we read the GET form HTML and define the variables we check against an array of allowed variables and there type, so id_client is checkd to be an INTEGER, if is NOT an INTEGER the script return an warning to the user, and stop execution. I think the solution is ok, if you don't please leave some arguments why is not a good solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that this code is at the end of the main code in the locallib.pl after this there are sub definitions, and locallib.pl is a library not a program file, so **it's last statement must returns true**, a simple 1; statement at the end of the library ensures that (put it after sub definitions to ensure that noobody writes code in the main after the 1;) and the problem was fixed.

The conclusion:
**I have learned that every time you write a library or modify one, ensure that it's last statment returns true;**

Answer (score -4):

Oh my... Try this as an example instead...

```
# Move the logic into a subroutine
# Forward definition so perl knows func exists
sub getClientIds($);       

# Call subroutine to find id's - defined later.
my @ids_from_database = &getClientIds("Joe Smith");

# If sub returned an empty list () then variable will be false.
# Otherwise, print each ID we found.

if (@ids_from_database) {
    foreach my $i (@ids_from_database) {
        print "Found ID $i \n";
    }
} else {
    print "Found nothing! \n";
}

# This is the end of the "main" code - now we define the logic.

# Here's the real work    
sub getClientIds($) {
    my $client = shift @_;       # assign first parameter to var $client
    my @ids    = ();             # what we will return

    # ensure we weren't called with &getClientIds("") or something...
    if (not $client) {
        print "I really need you to give me a parameter...\n";
        return @ids;
    }

    # I'm assuming the query is string based, so probably need to put it 
    # inside \"quotes\"
    my $st = &sql_query("select id from table where client=\"$client\"");

    # Did sql_query() fail?
    if (not $st) {
        print "Oops someone made a problem in the SQL...\n";
        return @ids;
    }

    my @result;

    # Returns a list, so putting it in a list and then pulling the first element
    # in two steps instead of one.
    while (@result = $st->fetchrow()) {
        push @ids, $result[0];
    }

    # Always a good idea to clean up once you're done.
    $st->finish();

    return @ids;
}
```

To your specific questions:

1. If you want to test if $client is defined, you want **"if ( eval { defined $client; } )"**, but that's almost certainly **NOT** what you're looking for!  It's far easier to ensure $client has some definition early in the program (e.g. **$client = "";**). Also note Kaklon's answer about the difference between **ne** and **!=**
2. **if (X) { stuff } else { }** is not valid perl.  You could do: **if (X) { stuff } else { 1; }** but that's kind of begging the question, because the real issue is the test of the variable, not an else clause.
3. Sorry, no clue on that - I think the problem's elsewhere.

I also echo Kinopiko in recommending you add **"use strict;"** at the start of your program.  That means that any $variable @that %you use has to be pre-defined as **"my $varable; my @that; my %you;"** It may seem like more work, but it's less work than trying to deal with undefined versus defined variables in code. It's a good habit to get into.

Note that **my** variables only live within the squiggliez in which they are defined (there's implicit squiggliez around the whole file:

```
my $x = 1;
if ($x == 1) 
{
    my $x = 2;
    print "$x \n";    # prints 2. This is NOT the same $x as was set to 1 above.
}
print "$x \n";        # prints 1, because the $x in the squiggliez is gone.
```

Comment: I will try your sugestion, use strict; is something that cannot be done beacause I'm adding this code to an old library (about 12 years old and not very well writen) that my company uses, and I will need to recode almost everiting to compile with strict :) I'm using PHP in my daily web scripts, but I need extend the perl library as well to add a new feature to the intranet.

Comment: !!!! Don't use prototypes! They aren't even being checked since you are calling subs with &! Prototypes weren't even meant to be used this way. In addition, subs shouldn't be called with & nor predeclared.

Comment: sql_query is not shown here, but it really needs to be refactored to allow for placeholders: $dbh->do( 'select id from table where client= ?', $client); otherwise you need to be ready to deal with http://xkcd.com/327/ And as mikegrb said, don't use proptotypes and don't call subs with &

Comment: 2. Perl does not care about an empty else clause.  `perl -e 'if (1) { print "stuff\n" } else { }'` causes no error.

Comment: 1. `eval` here is overkill.  `if (defined $client)` should work fine.